# No consigo capturar una excepción en Java para así evitar la detención del programa

Tags: java, excepciones

Hola que tal estoy retomando Java repasando conceptos básicos de programación, y me preguntaba por qué en este ejercicio no consigo capturar la excepción `InputMismatchException`.

Tengo una entrada de datos que te pide en bucle un número, mientras no sea 10 el programa te va a seguir pidiendo números, si es 10, finaliza. En caso de que el usuario introduzca un número, se imprime que Ha ocurrido un error y se le vuelve a pedir un número, entonces debería seguir ejecutándose el código, sin embargo veo que el programa deja de compilar y me muestra esa excepción.
Os dejo el código

```
package introJava;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Variables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num = 0;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
                num = entrada.nextFloat();
                
                if (num < 5) {
                    System.out.println("Se ha introducido menos de 5");
                }
                else if (num == 10) { 
                    num = 10;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("El número es mayor o igual a 5");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error");
                System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
                num = entrada.nextFloat();
            }
        } while (num != 10);
        System.out.println("Fin del programa");
        entrada.close();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desde el IDE eclipse.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Antes de llamar a nextFloat(), debes vaciar el flujo de entrada (input stream) porque nextFloat consumirá el carácter de salto de línea que habías introducido al pulsar tecla Enter (Intro). Lo idea sería usar nextLine() para obtener el texto completo hasta encontrar el salto de línea y tratar de convertirlo a float mediante Float.parseFloat( "string") o invocar scanner.nextLine() antes de ejecutar nextInt(), nextFloat(), etc.

Comment: en caso de usar Float.parseFloat o Integer.parseInt puedes capturar la excepción NumberFormatException.

Comment: Sí genial, lo pude solucionar, no recordaba que había que vaciar el flujo, al poner entrada.nextLine(), y luego el mensaje de error, todo correcto, gracias @nonameyet

Comment: genial, de nada